# How to save n number of values of a counter and then list it?

Tags: android

Basically what I want is to save, lets say 10 values(From the counter) with 10 different names and then show all these names in a list and let the user select one name.I have inflated a menu where i have put "Save" and "Open" options,Now when i press Save i want to save the value of counter at that instant with a name taken from the user and when i press Open i want to see a list where i can see all the saved values of the counter.
how can i achieve this,I have tried using SharedPreferences and Internal storage methods,but their outcomes doesn't seem to match what i mentioned above.Please show me how can i achieve this ??

MyActivity:(Relevant snippets from my code)

```
              Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); //touch on vibrate
            vb.vibrate(100);
            counter++;
            display.setText(""+counter);

        }
    });
    Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator vb=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); //touch on vibrate
            vb.vibrate(100);
            if(counter!=0)
            {
             counter--;
             display.setText(""+counter);
            }//if   
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.about:
        MyIntent();
        //setContentView(R.layout.aboutpage);
        break;
    case R.id.saveid:
         savefunc();
         break;
    case R.id.openid:
         openfunc();
         break;
    default:
        break; 
    }//switch
    return true;
}//onOptionsItemSelected        

    public void savefunc()
{
 SharedPreferences savecounter = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor= savecounter.edit();
 int your_home_score=0;
 editor.putInt("homescore", your_home_score);
 editor.apply();
}//savefunc

public void openfunc()
{
    SharedPreferences open = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int homescore = open.getInt("homescore",0);

}//openfunc
```

Comment: Are you trying to ask how can you save the values permanently or just during the sessions life cycle?

Comment: How have you used `SharedPreferences` and internal storage? What went wrong? What part(s) of the overall task do you need help with?